Can not find folder Image in ASP.NET MVC web application
I don't understand why the folder containing the "logo" image is missing when running a .NET Core MVC 6.0 program.
It caused my program to not work properly and I included some other folders in the same situation.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I also have a function when users upload images and then create a folder and save them there
But when I check on my computer, there is a folder + image files, but when I run the program, devtool doesn't exist
Hope everyone can give me advice and solutions <3

Does it works in development environment?  How is your Program.cs like? You said the devtool does not exist the folder? Could you pls share the screenshot?

Rena. Almost everything works fine except for a few image folders
